# twitter-bootstrap-rails - differences between development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm going crazy with this.
Using bootstrap for rails + less-rails gem and some styles are completely different on development and production.

Example:

a styles do have a black background-color on the hover event. I overwrote the a:hover style already via

```
background-color: none !important;
```

but it still shows up this weird black background on the hover event. Inspecting the element via Chrome does not even show this CSS style! So where does it come from?

Also, the font is different (dev vs live) and other minor things.
On the other hand, buttons and most major elements (well, lead etc etc) are working fine.

Where does this difference come from and how do I make dev versus live the same CSS appearance?

I deploy my app on heroku btw.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using other style on your application, something like a scaffold for generator, scaffold will generate scaffold css. I'm use scaffold and i'm having `scaffold.css.scss` on my apps, Here's style of link on `scaffold.css.scss`

```
a {
  color: #000;
  &:visited {
    color: #666;
  }
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

You should remove style of link or you can remove scaffold style on your apps if you won't it.

Twitter bootstrap do not have style link with a black background, by default.

If you don't have other style on your app and only use twitter bootstrap you should find style of link that bring about an issue

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I instantly thought about the same but I don't even have any scaffold css files in my stylesheet folder! I did not even use scaffolding for my app. I coded it from scratch.
I tried to find where the background-color tag is coming from while inspecting the link CSS tag - no success.
Also, I tried to overwrite the a:hover style but it does not work either (see OP). Something strange going on.

Comment: Ok I checked github and for whatever reason, the scaffolds.css.less file IS there, in my master branch. On my local repository it is not there. No clue why and how that has happened.

Comment: So the cause is scaffold, right? I also do not know why as it was, seemed to appear like a magic.